# How to put current date and time inside textbox in PHP Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, textbox, format

I am trying to put in my textbox the current time, with my preferred format (ex. 14:25:30)
What's wrong with my code? because when I run it, the textbox appears empty.

```
<td>
    <input id="date" name="curTime" size="20" maxlength="20"  Required />
</td>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var timenow = new Date();
    timenow.format("UTC:h:MM:ss TT Z");
    document.getElementById("date").value = new Date().toUTCString();
</script>
```

Comment: Javascript Date objects don't have a *format* method. Use the various [*Date.prototype.get**](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.10) methods to build the string to whatever format you want. Note that *toUTCString* is implementation dependent, so may be different in different browsers (but that is likely not an issue unless you are trying to parse the result).

Comment: PHP javascript ???? or PHP or javascript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format the current UTC time in javascript using a function like:

```
function getCurrentUTCTime() {
  var d = new Date();
  function z(n){ return (n<10? '0':'') + n;}
  return z(d.getUTCHours()) + ':' + 
         z(d.getUTCMinutes()) + ':' + 
         z(d.getUTCSeconds());
}
```

For local time:

```
function getCurrentTime() {
  var d = new Date();
  function z(n){ return (n<10? '0':'') + n;}
  return z(d.getHours()) + ':' + 
         z(d.getMinutes()) + ':' + 
         z(d.getSeconds());
}
```

Comment: You seemed to want UTC. If you want local time, just remove "UTC" from the *get* methods (and change the name of the function).

Comment: THANK YOU! :D
this is the answer that I've been looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no **format** function for a Date(), unless you have written one yourself. In which case, the error is probably in this function.

The format() call creates an error, but you are not using `timenow` anyway. I assume you intended to set the value to timenow.

You could borrow my format method, but it doesn't include UTC, TT or Z.

```
Date.prototype.format = function (sFormat, twelve) {
    // Returns: A string version of the date.
    // Usage: date_instance.format("d mmm yy hh:nn:ss ap") or 
    // date_instance.format("dddd dd mmmm hh:nn", true)
    // Defaults to YYYY/MM/DD.
    // twelve == true for a 12hr clock, or just AP or ap within 
    // sFormat (for AM/PM or am/pm).
    // Use z or zzz for milliseconds and xx for suffixes (st, nd, etc.).
    var MonthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    var DayNames = [ "Sunday", "Monday", "Tueday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
        "Friday", "Saturday" ];
    var dDate = this || new Date(),
        D = dDate.getDate(), DDDD = DayNames[dDate.getDay()], 
        DDD = DDDD.substr(0,3),
        M = dDate.getMonth()+1, MMMM = MonthNames[dDate.getMonth()], 
        MMM = MMMM.substr(0,3),
        YYYY = dDate.getFullYear(), YY = ('' + YYYY).substr(2, 2),
        H = dDate.getHours(), N = dDate.getMinutes(), S = dDate.getSeconds(),
        Z = dDate.getMilliseconds(),
        ap = (H > 11) ? "pm" : "am",
        // pad with leading zeros, if required
        DD = ( D < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + D,
        MM = ( M < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + M,
        NN = ( N < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + N, 
        SS = ( S < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + S,
        ZZZ = ( Z < 10 ? "00" : (Z < 100 ? "0" : "") ) + Z, XX;
    var AP = (sFormat && (sFormat.toUpperCase().indexOf('AP')+1)) ? 
        ((sFormat.indexOf('ap')+1) ? ap : ap.toUpperCase()) : '';
    if (twelve || AP) {
        H = (H < 12) ? (H || 12) : ((H - 12) || 12);
    }
    var HH = ( H < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + H;
    XX = (D == 1 || D == 21 || D == 31) ? "st" : 
        ((D == 2 || D == 22) ? "nd" : ((D == 3 || D == 23) ? "rd" : "th"));
    sFormat = ( sFormat ) ? sFormat.toUpperCase() : 'YYYY/MM/DD';
    var sParsed = sFormat.replace(/D{1,4}|M{1,4}|Y{2,4}|H{1,2}|N{1,2}|S{1,2}|Z{1,3}|XX|AP/g,
        function (m) {
            try {
                return eval(m);
            } catch (e) {
                return '';
            }
        });
    return sParsed;
};
```

I use 'nn' for minutes, reserving 'mm' for the month.

Comment: It would be a good thing to spend 10 minutes getting rid of *eval* and *try..catch*, they are completely unnecessary here.

Comment: @RobG. How can I translate 'M' into its variable equivalent? Neither `this[m]` nor `window[m]` give the value(s). (I have another version that doesn't use eval() but it was a little more cumbersome.)

Comment: I could, I suppose, create another variable to attach the attributes (M, MM, etc.) to, but this just makes the code messier. I'm happy to use eval() and try..catch on this very rare occasion. Unless @RobG proposes a simple solution.

Comment: Instead of creating the values as variables (`DD`, `MM`, etc.), make them named properties of an object. Then match the named properties in the replace function (e.g. `return m in obj? obj[m] : '';`). That's effectively what you're doing with *eval* (i.e. using strings to access named properties of the variable object).

Comment: Thank you @RobG. Yes, I realised that I would need to attach these properties to an object. I thought it would be messy but, hey!, this is JS and it only requires minimal code. I thought I had found a legitimate reason to use eval() but I am always persuaded by a ternary ;)

Comment: @AndyG—I've used eval in a calculator: building a mathematic expression then eval'ing it is much easier than processing the expression yourself. There may be other cases for running arbitrary code, but I haven't had to resort to that yet.

Answer (score 0):

change your javascript to this.

```
var timenow = new Date();
 document.getElementById("date").value = timenow.toString();
```

the format function `format()` is a php thing, to print the date as a string in the text box use the `toString()` function.

you can set the format of the date in the `toString()` function

Comment: `toString()` doesn't take any arguments so the format-characters don't work.

Comment: it gives me the complete date and time :(

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your javascript(24 hour format)

```
<script>
 {
 var today=new Date();
 var t=today.toLocaleTimeString("en-GB");
  document.getElementById("date").value=t;
 }
</script>
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: The OP seems to want UTC, and *toLocaleTimeString* does not guarantee the required format as it's implementation dependent (and isn't in the required format in Safari at least).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with builtin functions of PHP

```
<input id="date" name="curTime" value="<?php echo date('D-M-Y')." ".gmdate("H:i:s", time()); ?>" size="20" maxlength="20"  Required />
```